# CanvasJS - Chart with Multiple Y Axis and Hide Unhide Data Series on Legend Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

I use [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/) in my project and it worked fine until now.

Here is the two examples from the web site :

[Multiple Y Axis](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/multiple-y-axis/)

[Hide Unhide Data Series on Legend Click](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/hide-unhide-data-series-chart-legend-click/)

Since i added the option `maximum:` to my Axis Y2-2 var the scale no longer hides by clicking in the legend !

Here is my [JSfiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/onrfpxa5/)

Can you help me to debug it please ?

Comment: You can set maximum to null on click of legend. That will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this issue and here an workable example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdffL6nc/).

```
if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
  e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  if (e.dataSeriesIndex == 2) {
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].valueFormatString = " ";
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].title = null;
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].lineColor = "#BBBBBB";
  };
}
else {
  e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  if (e.dataSeriesIndex == 2) {
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].valueFormatString = "#,##0.##";
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].title = "Linear Scale";
    e.chart.options.axisY2[0].lineColor = "#7F6084";
  };
}
```

I hope that can help someone else :)